# Alter color during OpenGL rendering without lighting or shaders

Tags: opengl

I need to render an object using an existing texture, and I need to alter the color during the rendering. (Such as multiplying red channel by 0.5.) The existing texture is not monochromatic. I need to do this without enabling lighting and without shaders so I don't disturb the application I'm working within. I cannot work early enough in the rendering that I could read/write the buffer directly.

In effect, I'd like some sort of color-transformation matrix or filter that works during normal rendering.

Comment: Don't disturb the application, what is that supposed to mean? Are you doing some sort of DLL injection?

Comment: Also which API version (OpenGL) are you targeting?

Comment: OpenGL 2 or below, and it's injection of code in a Java program with user direction. GPU memory is premium but GPU processing is underutilized, so computation rather than additional textures is better. The program uses nasty hacks instead of proper lighting code so it's not easily replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base in the limited information I'll assume some things.

I'll assume you are working with fixed pipeline. 
I'll assume you are not using a low level pixel function like glBitmap or glDrawPixels. If you are you should not.

To solve you problem try the following:
Draw a textured quad, using glBegin,glEnd,glVertex2f,glTexCoord2f
To alter the color use glColor just after glBegin and before any other draw instruction.
You should do your color-transformation matrix in the cpu and use that result with glColor.

Image will be blended accordingly. WHITE doesn't change the image color. 
Make sure GL_LIGHTING is not enabled.

Comment: This sounds interesting, and I will try it tonight. The program is using fixed pipeline rather than proper code, yes, and it is just drawing textured quads.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL has a color transformation matrix (GL_COLOR) that can be accessed and modified just like GL_MODELVIEW or GL_PROJECTION (you will most probably need glLoadMatrix or glMultMatrix, as glRotate and such doesn't make much sense with colors). It requires the extension GL_ARB_imaging.

Comment: I was told that works only during direct pixel transfers and not during normal rendering.